# Перемещение файла python

Tags: python, файлы, файловая-система, перемещение

**Здравствуйте, возникла проблема:**
На сервере, файлы скачиваются в определённую папку (пусть это будет) `'/home/instaparser/:stories'`, и при отображении фотографий и видео они не видны на web-странице. Я узнал, что если фото и видео будут в папке `'/home/instaparser/mysite/static/:stories'`, то их можно будет увидеть на web-странице.

**Вопрос заключается в следующем:**
Можно ли кодом на python написать какой-нибудь цикл, который все файлы из одной папки переносит в другую папку, которую сам создаёт?

Искал в интернете ответы на вопрос, пробовал через `Path().rename()`, пробую через `shutil.move()`, каждый раз выдаёт ошибки, типа:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/instaparser/mysite/:stories/2021-06-25_20-02-47_UTC.jpg' -> '/home/instaparser/mysi te/static/:stories/2021-06-25_20-02-47_UTC.jpg'`

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

UPD: (привожу код)

```
file_path = '/home/instaparser/mysite/static/:stories'

for _ in glob.glob(f'{file_path}/*'): # Удаляем предыдущие истории в папке :stories
    os.remove(_)
L.download_stories(userids=[profile.userid]) # Скачиваем новые истории в папке :stories

try:
    download_path = '/home/instaparser/:stories'
    path, dirs, files = next(os.walk(f'{download_path}'))
except Exception:
    download_path = '/home/instaparser/mysite/:stories'
    path, dirs, files = next(os.walk(f'{download_path}'))

for _ in files:
    Path(f'{download_path}/{_}').rename(f'{file_path}/{_}')

for _ in glob.glob(r'/{file_path}/*.json.xz'): # Удаляем файлы с метаданными (расширение .json.xz)
    os.remove(_)
```

Comment: Приведите ваш код в вопросе.

Comment: @insolor, Исправил.

Comment: А разве может быть двоеточие в названиях папок или файлов?

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, библиотека instaloader загружает файлы по умолчанию в папку :stories